# PyZMQ how to send None data over ZeroMQ

Tags: null, zeromq, pyzmq

The first node in my PubSub network is reading a .csv file, and is forwarding the data row-by-row as multi-part messages. After sending the last row, I want to send a final message with `None` to indicate to the rest of my network that we're finished.

E.g. message envelope: `pub.send_multipart(['some_topic'.encode('ascii'), None])`

However, if I try to send that, I get the following error:

```
TypeError('Frame 1 (None) does not support the buffer interface.',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/*path*/anaconda3/envs/zeromq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 426, in send_multipart
    memoryview(msg)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pub_facs.py", line 165, in facs_pub
    await pub.send_multipart([sub_key.encode('ascii'), None, None, None, None])
  File "/*path*/anaconda3/envs/zeromq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/_future.py", line 445, in _handle_send
    result = send(msg, **kwargs)
  File "/*path*/anaconda3/envs/zeromq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 433, in send_multipart
    i, rmsg,
TypeError: Frame 1 (None) does not support the buffer interface.
```

Of course, I could set it to something like `['some_topic', -1]`, but if I want to do automatic object assignment in another programming language, such as C#, setting the data as `null` would work, but -1 not, if that variable is not initialized as an integer.

What is the best way to send an empty message over ZeroMQ (PyZMQ)? Can I somehow send an empty message frame? The ZeroMQ guide speaks about `zmq_msg_init()` to create an empty message in C, but I don't know how to do that in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simple way to send a "None" message: `b''` (empty byte String), e.g. Python >=3.5 (asyncio):

```
# send None message
await pub.send_multipart([sub_key.encode('ascii'), b'', b''])

# receive None message
msg = await sub.recv_multipart()
if msg[1]:
    # do stuff with message
else:
    print("Message is empty")
```

With C#:

```
if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out topic)) continue;
if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out data1)) continue;
if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out data2)) continue;

if (data1 != "")
{
    // Do message stuff
}
```

I haven't tested with other languages, but I have a feeling that would be similiar easy.

Answer (score 0):

### What is the best way to send an empty message over ZeroMQ?

Your problem is called a need to have the same SER/DES strategy on either of the sides involved.

ZeroMQ is not the part to be blamed for this sort of problems.

In case your selected language binding ( PyZMQ ) does not permit to handle and send a **`None`** data type, your next step may go via **`import struct`** and composing
**`struct.pack(   aDateTypeSpecificMASK, aDataToSEND )`** / decoding data-types **`struct.unpack( aDateTypeSpecificMASK, aDataJustRECVd )`** according to your own bits/bytes-mapping policies ( this may sound laborious, but just on one's first sight as you remain in absolute control for any individual remote-end client ecosystem and **that is the most powerful option**, isn't it? )

ZeroMQ will "just carry" the bits/bytes-mapped payloads without any intervention. That simple.